# Saving Key with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

When saving a Objectify Entity to the Appengine datastore, is it possible to save a custom Datastore "Key" instead of the auto generated Key hash?

Comment: No, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any String or long and annotate it as being the key, like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class MyEntityClass {
  @Id
  private String myCustomKey;

  public MyEntityClass(String keyId) {
    this.myCustomKey = keyId;
  }
}
```

Then you can retrieve it again using:

```
MyEntityClass object = ofy().get(new Key<MyEntityClass>(MyEntitiyClass.class, "specificKeyId"));
```

Comment: Even if I do this the myCustomeKey will be stored in the "ID/name" column. I was thinking more of storing in the "Key" column of the datastore

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misunderstood the question.

I don't know whether you can change the encoded entity key, e.g. "agtzfnNwbGlueGFwcHIbCxIER2F..", which is generated from the key name, entity kind, ancestors, app ID etc.